# Haskell 'unpacking' monad

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod

I do not have a good grip on monads in Haskell, and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

The following piece of code is covered in a do statement.

```
(...)
x <- runDB $ do
    receipts <- selectList [] []
    users <- selectList [] []
    receiptUsers <- selectList [] []
    return $ joinTables3 receiptUserUserId receiptUserReceiptId receiptUsers users receipts
let allUsers = runDB $ do 
    receipts <- selectList [] []
    users <- selectList [] []
    receiptUsers <- selectList [] []
    return $ joinTables3 receiptUserUserId receiptUserReceiptId receiptUsers users receipts

let answer = functionUsingValue x --functionUsingValue allUsers
(...)
```

It not clear for every variable what it is here, but I hope this is not a problem for my issue.

My goal is to create a function which returns exactly the same value as is stored in x, but what I have now is not right, instead the function returns a monad. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TypSignaturez, plz...   _seriously_, you need to tell us what monad this is you're working on. In general, it's not possible to just extract values from a monad in any other other than using the bind operation, i.e. "staying in the monad". "Exiting the monad" is only possible for spefic instances such as `State`. — Another thing that would be nice is if you actually made use of the `do` notation: `action >>= (\val -> ...)` should be written `do { val <- action; ... }`.

Comment: I edited my code. Give me some time to think about the monad.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I find it particulary strange that I can use x as the argument for the function functionUsingValue, but that I cannot create a function which returns exactly x. Could you explain to me if this is possible at all or why this would not be possible? I do not understand why this is monad-specific.

Comment: Could you try to put together a minimal example of what's confusing to you? There's a lot going on in your example code.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Abrahamson I find it hard to create an example as my knowledge of monads is not good enough to create one myself, but will try to explain what confuses me. I am trying to create a function which substitutes the first part of my code where I store a value in x. My final goal is a function with arguments which does exactly what the x part does and then returns that value so I can use it like I use x right now. The problem with the function I have written is the value it returns is still contained in the monad. Am I trying to use monads in a faulty way?

Comment: @AartStuurman I believe that what you're trying to do is impossible (and @jozefg below corroborates that), but really it's an artifact of not using monads correctly. If you have a value `a` that's "wrapped" in a monad `m` like this: `m a` then you *want* to and in fact often *must* carry around that `m`-context with your value. Haskell lets you pretend somewhat like `m a` is just like `a` and both `do` notation and `(>>=)` help to perpetuate that belief. Instead of trying to escape the monad, use `fmap`, `join`, and `(>>=)` to sneak your functions **into** `m` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I did a bit of digging and the answer is... no. `runDB` spits out a result in Yesod's `GHandler` monad. However, this monad is really the composition of several monads including `IO`.

Any function of type `IO a -> a` is very unsafe in Haskell, since there's no guarantees about when or even if the side effects occurring in the `IO` monad will run! Since `GHandler` includes `IO` in there, you can't run it, doing so would mean you could derive something of type `IO a -> a` like this

```
uhoh :: IO a -> a
uhoh = runGHandler . liftIO
```

So if you want to use `x` in pure code, the gist is that you write your pure code

```
foo :: a -> b
```

then you use this in your code

```
myHandler = do
  x <- runDB $ ...
  let x' = foo x
  saveTheWorldWith x'
```

But all your code that's "dirtied" by your monad has to stay together. Because of this, in general you want to minimize the code that's "impure" and instead focus on writing pure functions and using them in your impure computations.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will try to avoid this and use another way of solving my problem without using a function as I am trying to make.